# How can I add a Hashtable into a NameValuePair?

Tags: java, android, httpclient, hashtable

I want to add a Hashtable as the value of a NameValuePair as follows:

`name= credit_card`

`value(this is the hashtable)= {expirationDate="2013/02/18", ownerName="Jack Sparrow", typeOfCard="C2"}`

or like this:

new BasicNameValuePair("credit_card",{expirationDate="2013/02/18", ownerName="Jack Sparrow", typeOfCard="C2"}).

This is part of my code and  you can you can see how I'm adding a simple NameValuePair:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://example.com/register");
try {
  List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
  nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user", user));
  nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
  post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

  HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean "add a hash"?

Comment: What `hash` are you talking about here?

Comment: as you can see the BasicNameValuePair constructor is BasicNameValuePair(String name, String value)   http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/message/BasicNameValuePair.html

Comment: @Carlos - are you trying to add a hash of the JSON string, as a BasicNameValuePair, with the key 'credit_card'? Basically new BasicNameValuePair("credit_card", hash(json))?

Comment: @Perception, that's what I am also thinking. Basis on that I have provided an answer below.

Comment: @Perception and TechGeeky I added more code in order to show you a better idea of what I'm talking about! Thanks for your time!

Comment: The code you added doesn't answer the follow-up questions we asked. But you can browse the answers below and see if they are helpful.

Comment: @Perception I want something like new BasicNameValuePair("credit_card",{expirationDate="2013/02/18", ownerName="Jack Sparrow", typeOfCard="C2"})

Comment: @TechGeeky please see the above comment and let me know if now I'm more clear! thanks!!

Comment: @Carlos, You modified your question from Hash to HashTable now ;). So the below answers obviously will not match your question now. I thinki you can add the String `your_json` as the value of `BasicNameValuePair`. If you are doing like that, then what problem are you facing?

Comment: @TechGeeky sorry for my noob mistake! My problem now is that the BasicNameValuePair constructor is(String,String) and I need (String,Hashtable)

Comment: Why do you need that as a HashTable? It is mandatory? Or you can convert that HashTable value to String. Right?

Comment: I can convert it to String but it should look like "expirationDate="2013/02/18", ownerName="Jack Sparrow", typeOfCard="C2""

Comment: It will look like that way. Try converting that object to String. And while debugging try to see how it is looking to you.

Comment: It looks good by doing a hastable.toString(); Tomorrow I'll let you know if that is working in my service and I'll post the answer in case yes!! Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Apache DigestUtils](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/digest/DigestUtils.html) to compute a hash very easily:

```
String hash = DigestUtils.sha512Hex(json);
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("credit_card", hash));
```

Or you could use the Java Cryptography API directly:

```
final Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
final MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest
        .getInstance("SHA-512");
final byte[] hashData = digest
        .digest(json.getBytes(charset));
final String hash = new String(hashData, charset);
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("credit_card", hash));
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure I am understanding your question properly. But I am giving a try here-

`String message = "hello";`

`System.out.println( DigestUtils.md5Hex(message) );`

So you can modify your `add` method of `nameValuePairs` something like below.

`new BasicNameValuePair("credit_card", DigestUtils.md5Hex(your_json))`

Here is the [manual](http://commons.apache.org/codec/api-release/org/apache/commons/codec/digest/DigestUtils.html)

**Updated Answer after question is updated**

If you HashTable value is a String then you can add it like this in your `nameValuePair`

`new BasicNameValuePair("credit_card", (your_json))`